# TCP proxy client-client and server-server connectors - Does anything like this already exist?

Tags: tcp, proxy

I currently have a bunch of different TCP applications that are servers or clients depending on there intent. I have a few special configuration cases where the applications need to connected in a odd way.

The problem I am having is I sometimes need to connect up two applications (tcp client to client) and (tcp server to server). While there are a few raw TCP proxy applications out there, like https://code.google.com/p/tcproxy/, which typically do (server to client(s)).

Is there any applications, like tcpproxy, which will act as a proxy between (client(s) to client(s)) and (server to server(s)) TCP applications. The system just needs a simple command-line application that forwards bytes around, and it seems like I can't be the first person to need such an app. Google search is not helping me out here.

Comment: You can probably do this using `socat`.

Comment: Wow. I wish I knew about "socat" before. It should work nicely. Thankyou.